# Call the output generated in UI to server using custom message

Tags: javascript, shiny

Is there a way to generate the output generated in UI  to be rendered in server.
Basically , whatever is input in numeric input (id = "hcontent"),
`output$tab` to have +1

So by default the value is 2, so `output$tab` to have 3

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # HTML('<p id="res">Value</p>'),
  # textInput("x", label = "Text"),
  # tags$script("document.getElementById('res').innerHTMl=x")
  
  HTML(
  
"<h1>Change the HTML content</h1>
<h2 id=\"hcontent\">2</h2> 
<h3>Welcome</h3>
<input id='x' type=\"number\" oninput = 'searchURL()'></input>
<script>  

function searchURL() {
     document.getElementById(\"hcontent\").innerHTML=x.value
}
</script> 

"
       
       
       ),
tags$script("Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('handler1', searchURL)"),
htmlOutput("tab")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$tab <- renderUI({
    session$sendCustomMessage("handler1", input$hcontent+1)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure this is what you want because your code is confusing. Please give a try and tell me whether this is ok.

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(HTML("
      function searchURL(x) {
        document.getElementById(\"paragraph\").innerHTML = x;
      }                 
    "))
  ),
  
  tags$h1("Change the HTML content"),
  
  tags$h2(
    numericInput("hcontent", "", value = 2)
  ),
  
  tags$h3("Welcome"),
  
  tags$p(id = "paragraph"),
  
  tags$script(HTML("Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('handler1', searchURL)"))
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input[["hcontent"]], {
    session$sendCustomMessage("handler1", input[["hcontent"]]+1)
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```